# Ruby - Changing value of an array hashes value

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash from a json decode:

> {"person"=>{"user"=>[{"username"=>"foo", "status"=>"Y",
>   "roles"=>["accounting", "sales"]}]}}

I basically want to change the roles value to be in a comma delimited sentence like doing value.to_sentence. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to turn `["accounting", "sales"]` into `"accounting, sales"`?

Comment: Yes that what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```ruby
def fix_roles(h)
  user0 = h['person']['user'][0]
  user0['roles'] = user0['roles'].join(', ')
end
```

**[Edit]** For example:

```ruby
h = {"person"=>{"user"=>[{"username"=>"foo", "status"=>"Y", "roles"=>["accounting", "sales"]}]}}
fix_roles(h)
h # => {"person"=>{"user"=>[{"username"=>"foo", "status"=>"Y", "roles"=>"accounting, sales"}]}}
```

Comment: I get TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

Comment: @oprogfrogo: if you copy your hash into a variable, say "`h`" and call "`fix_roles(h)`" then your hash will be modified as you describe.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. That works with the first element in the array. How can I make it update when there are multiple elements. Like this: h = {"person"=>{"user"=>[{"username"=>"foo", "status"=>"Y", "roles"=>["accounting", "sales"]}, {"username"=>"bar", "status"=>"Y", "roles"=>["customer service", "sales"]}]}}

Comment: Thanks for showing the path. I've figured out how to iterate through it and it works now:

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to maerics example, I was able to achieve the solution by iterating through each array element:

```
def fix_roles(w)
  w['person']['user'].each do |arr|
    arr.each do |k,v|
      arr['roles'] = v.join(', ') if k == 'roles' 
    end
  end
end
```